# conda env list shows one of my environments twice, although it only exists once in my directory?

Tags: anaconda, conda

Using Anaconda Prompt, I run

```
conda env list
```

I then receive one of my environments twice? For example:

> base                       *  C:\Users\myuser\anaconda3
> new_env                    C:\Users\myuser\anaconda3\envs\new_env   
> another_env              C:\Users\myuser\anaconda3\envs\another_env 
> new_env                    C:\Users\myuser\anaconda3\envs\new_env

I am on a windows system, and the simplest way for me to solve it, was to go to the 'anaconda3\' directory, move all env folders out of the directory, and then back in.

But I am wondering why it is happening in the first place?

Comment: Not enough info. To actually troubleshoot this one would need the `conda info` output, `conda config --show-sources` output, and possibly a look at the `~/.conda/environments.txt`. My best guess is there are duplicate entries in the `environments.txt`, which one can freely delete.